# Semantic web: populate a triplestore accessible from my Android application

Tags: android, api, semantic-web, triplestore, triples

Here the story: I was developing a mobile application for my MSc project. Thi application was relying on an open dataset on the website www.kasabi.com, a marketplace for open data.
It was everything perfect until they ended up saying "we're gonna shut down the website".
You can understand that now I'm quite....well, I let you imagine.

the dataset is still available and downloadable so what I have now is: A server on Amazon, a backup file of the kasabi dataset (triples) and...nothing else.

I looked around for tutorial on how to develope semantic web applications, but I still don't have any idea on how to use this backup file in order to set up a triplestore and make it accessible from my android applications.

suggestions?

Comment: In what way were you accessing the data when it was on Kasabi? Was it through a SPARQL interface or something else?

Comment: yes...they had a sparql endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Apache Jena on your server (if amazon allows this):
http://jena.apache.org/index.html

Then you can access data in in a similar way to what you are used to in kasabi.

But you might like to have a look thorugh [Which Triplestore for rapid semantic web development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304920/which-triplestore-for-rapid-semantic-web-development?rq=1) , possibly Sesame would suit you better (http://www.openrdf.org/)

Comment: I'm trying sesame...but i don't understand how to load this .nt (n-quads) file...it seems like it doesn't support this format...am i right?

Comment: I'm no Sesame expert but I'd be surprised if it didn't load ab N-Triples format. Maybe your file should have an .nq extension as documented here: http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/api/org/openrdf/rio/RDFFormat.html

Comment: There's a difference between N-Triples (.nt) and N-Quads (.nq). Sesame supports N-Triples out of the box, but currently has no built-in N-Quads parser available. We are working on this, but in the mean time there are several Sesame-compatible N-Quads parsers available from third parties. See http://www.openrdf.org/issues/browse/SES-802.